# p4 print command help need in perl

Tags: perl, perforce

hi i have written a code

```perl
#!/tools/baton/perl/5.12.1/bin/perl

use strict;

use YAML;


use YAML 'LoadFile';

use Data::Dumper;

my $file_yml;

my $path = "//IP2/D21EV/2hw/semi_axi_10g_ethernet/info.yml";

 my %hash = open(READ, p4 print -q $path|") or die "could not open ";

print Dumper (\%hash);
```

it is giving me :

```
$VAR1 = {

          '39807' => undef

        };
```

Comment: i need print the info.yml file which is  in perforce , which is every big file with lot of key/vaule paris , but on output i am seeing some number ,can some expalin what happing here.

Comment: The code in the question contains syntax errors. Please [edit] your question using the [edit] link on the bottom right and fix those. Why are you using YAML, but then you are just reading a file yourself (with old-fashioned two-arg-open and lexical filehandle!)? Also, what is `p4`?

Answer (score 5):

You have some syntax errors in your code (missing double quote), but it's probably just copy'n'paste problem.

The main problem seems to be you used the value returned by [open](http://p3rl.org/open) to populate the hash, but `open` doesn't return the contents of the file. In fact, as documented, it returns the PID of the child process if you use it to open a pipe.

You need to actually **read** from the file handle to get its contents.

E.g.

```
my %hash;
open my $PIPE, '-|', qw( ls -s );
while (<$PIPE>) {
    my ($size, $file) = split;
    $hash{$file} = $size;
}
```

Comment: hi choroba thanks for reply but i am so  not good with coding can help me here  by some sample code ..

Comment: @herp: See [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline) and [open](http://p3rl.org/open).

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply but the p4 print command will print data into in harsh file right in above code , i am trying like this because i am not good programmer

Comment: some snippet would be nice

Comment: but i above snippet ur not using p4 print ..how move data from p4 print to hash file ?

Comment: the problem i ma new born babe in perl and more ever i am not programmer

Comment: hi choroba i am not  able to print the hash , i am not able to move data can let know how move data and print

Comment: @herp: It's time you start reading the documentation. Start from [perlintro](http://p3rl.org/perlintro).